# Bitbucket to github migration of an already existing repo

Tags: github, migration, bitbucket

we have migrated from bitbucket to github 4 months ago but our team members are still using bitbucket. So, now we have decided to completely moved to Github and use its sevices. So, i want to know whether we can still use mirroring or not to  migrate all the changes in bitbucket to github or we have to push it manually or using **git push --all**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if there was concurrent activity both on GitHub (the new repository) and BitBucket (the old one)

If that is the case, I would prefer asking each developer, in their own local repository, to:

- add the new repository as a remote 'gh'
- fetch from it
- rebase their branch on top of gh/their-branch (for branches that were modified both on GitHub and BitBucket)
- push new branches (done only on BitBucket)

That way, each developer can resolve any conflict locally first, before updating the new GitHub repository.